# make a dictionary out of first elements in a list of list

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

This is a question about performance of using **set() on list comprehension inside dictionary comprehension Vs dictionary comprehension and repeated assignment to a new dictionary**

So I happen to have a dataset which is a list of lists and i need to get a unique list of elements that are indexed at '0' in each of those lists inside the big list, so as to be able to make a new dictionary from them.. something like dict.fromkeys() .. here I need to supply list of unique keys..

I'm using

[1] `{ x : [] for x in set([i[0] for i in data])}`

and also using

[2] `{ i[0] : [] for i in data}`

sample data for reference here could be like:
`[[1,3,4], [3,5,2], [1,5,2]]`

the result from running [1] and [2] above would then be:
`{ 1:[], 3: [] }`

I tried %timeit on both statements and both give nearly same results which makes it difficult to identify which one is best, performance-wise, for big list of lists

How do I identify a potential bottleneck here?

**EDIT:**

If this helps in explaining the results..

```
In [172]: data_new = data * 10000

In [173]: %timeit { i[0] : [] for i in data_new}
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop

In [174]: %timeit { x : [] for x in set([i[0] for i in data_new])}
10 loops, best of 3: 131 ms per loop

In [175]: data_new = data * 100000

In [176]: %timeit { x : [] for x in set([i[0] for i in data_new])}
1 loops, best of 3: 1.37 s per loop

In [177]: %timeit { i[0] : [] for i in data_new}
1 loops, best of 3: 1.58 s per loop

In [178]: data_new = data * 1000000

In [179]: %timeit { i[0] : [] for i in data_new}
1 loops, best of 3: 15.8 s per loop

In [180]: %timeit { x : [] for x in set([i[0] for i in data_new])}
1 loops, best of 3: 13.6 s per loop
```

Comment: Generate a lot of random data and use that and re-time... **2** will come out quicker in the end as it's doing a lot less work (eg: not building a list, then building a set)

Comment: The difference in timing is equal to the time it takes to make the extra `set` in #1... that's a few ms on a million-element list.  In other words, look elsewhere for a bottleneck.

Comment: You cannot use `dict.fromkeys` here because the `dict.fromkeys(..., [])` will share the list, which probably what you may not want

Comment: @thefourtheye I agree. I didn't. Mentioned it just to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve here..

Comment: @JonClements Surprisingly, **1** came out to be quicker.. I'll add results in edit in question.. anyway, still looking for an explanation.. maybe something related to set() developed in C library with a sound algorithm for sorting,, and assigning keys to existing dictionary being slower than the former.

Comment: 1st can be quicker because it does not recreate new empty lists for each duplicate key. 2nd could also be faster with some other values and especially if there are not many duplicates.

Comment: The dictionary and set on the other hand behave mostly identically...

Comment: @roippi I used a length of 206000000 for final %timeit. and difference became 2.2 s. But I get your point. Still a description of how [1] is faster than [2] eventually would be great! :)

Comment: @arcolife Can you please try this also `set(i[0] for i in data_new)`?

Comment: Even faster is using a set-comp `{ x: [] for x in {i[0] for i in data}}`... - that implies `dict`s replacing duplicate keys is the bottle neck

Comment: Yeah, dict() does need to do extra refcounting and stuff, whereas set() just says "ok the key is here, now move along".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build a larger dataset, then timeit:

**Code:**

```
import random
data = [ [random.randint(1, 9) for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(1000000)]
```

**Timings:**

```
%timeit { x : [] for x in set([i[0] for i in data])}
# 10 loops, best of 3: 94.6 ms per loop
%timeit { i[0] : [] for i in data}
# 10 loops, best of 3: 106 ms per loop
%timeit { x: [] for x in set(i[0] for i in data)}
# 10 loops, best of 3: 114 ms per loop
%timeit { x: [] for x in {i[0] for i in data}}
# 10 loops, best of 3: 77.7 ms per loop
```

**Rationale**:

Limiting the available key space first means the dictionary only has to assign (given the `randint` above) 9 unique keys to 9 new lists. When using a dict comp, the dictionary has to repeatedly create and re-assign the value of its key to a *newly created* list... The difference is overhead in the deallocation of discarded empty lists (being garbage collected) and the time spent to create a *new* empty list.

Given a uniform distribution from `randint`, then there's 111,111 allocations and de-allocations of empty lists for 9 unique values over a set of 1,000,000 elements -- that's a lot more than just 9.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how many duplicates you expect. In the shorter code, the empty list is created for each item in the input list, and this is surprisingly expensive. Use a static value, and the shorter becomes faster.

In the following, `L = [[1,3,4], [3,5,2], [1,5,2]] * 100000`

```
In [1]: %timeit { x : [] for x in {i[0] for i in L]}}
10 loops, best of 3: 58.9 ms per loop

In [2]: %timeit { i[0] : [] for i in L}
10 loops, best of 3: 68.1 ms per loop
```

Now test with the constant `None` value here:

```
In [3]: %timeit { x : None for x in set([i[0] for i in L])}
10 loops, best of 3: 59 ms per loop

In [4]: %timeit { i[0] : None for i in L}
10 loops, best of 3: 54.3 ms per loop
```

Thus the needless list creation makes the shorter one perform slowly, whereas it is absolutely faster with constant values.

---

I didn't have ipython for Python 2 and I am a bit lazy timing this, but you would want to notice that Python 2.7 supports **set comprehensions**, which at least on Python 3.4 are much faster than creating sets from lists:

```
In [7]: %timeit { x : [] for x in {i[0] for i in L}}
10 loops, best of 3: 48.9 ms per loop
```